# Display specific number of items in Windows 8 (Js/html) APP

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-8, grid

I am currently building a Windows 8 Html/js App and started with the gridview template because that spared me a lot of time styling most of the app.

I have successfully managed to adapt the Windows 8 split screen tutorial (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974582.aspx) to the app I'm building. In this app, I'm reading data from an rss feed, just like in the tutorial. But in my example, I get 60+ items. This is good, but I don't want to display all 60 items at my home page... I do want all of them to display in the groupDetails page.

What I did now is the following: In my homescreen I only want like 12 items to dislay, so in in my data.js file, while going through all the posts I'm checking this and if it's one of the first 12, it'll get a reference 'show', otherwise this is 'hide'. like this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < posts.length ; i++) {
        var post = posts[i];
        //get the title
        var postTitle = post.querySelector("title").textContent;
        //get the content
        var staticContent = toStaticHTML(post.querySelector("content,encoded").textContent);
        var ref = "show";
        if (i > 11) {
            ref = "hide";
        }
        //store the post info we care about
        cPosts.push({
            group: feed,
            backgroundImage: "http://www.thesedays.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/LTT_220_11.jpg",
            key: feed.key,
            ref: ref,
            title: postTitle,
            content: staticContent,
            description: feed.description
        });
    }
```

Now I'm not familiar with datapromises, but I can simple hide these elements with .hide() (i added the jQuery library to my project), but I'm not sure when all the items are loaded...

Anybody that can help me out with this?
You can view the complete data.js file here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj663506.aspx

Comment: In general, I'd say this is mixing UI and data model. I'd be more inclined to create a new WinJS.Binding.List from something like cposts.slice(0, 12) and make that the list the one you assign to listView.groupDataSource for the home page.  I didn't have a chance to try it out, but maybe it'll get you in the right direction. (In C#/XAML, for instance, you'd just set DataContext to fullarray.Take(12), slice should be pretty close to that)

Comment: tnx, it worked that way! But I thought there would be a more cleaner way then just adding another list. I really like the Windows 8  html/js way so I thought there would be a cleaner way. Because you'r reading an rss feed, you can sometimes not know how big it is and you don't want to overkill your user with 200.000 tiles :)

Comment: well, I'd question whether you'd bring down 200,000 in one fell swoop anyway versus incrementally loading, in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had enough reputation to leave a comment I would have, since it seems like you already have a working solution. But I just wanted to mention an alternative. You could use a [filtered projection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700741.aspx) of your binding list since you are already modifying your data to mark the elements that you want to show. The code might look something like this:

```
cPosts.createFiltered(function (item) {
    return item.ref === 'show';
});
```